# How to substract values from a dataframe based on a reference value stored in another dataframe in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a first dataframe that contains values in five levels of a factor, with three repetitions of each level.

```
set.seed(66)

df1 <-
    data.frame(
        repetition = rep(1:3, 5),
        condition = rep(letters[1:5], each = 3),
        value = rnorm(5)
        )
```

which looks like:

```
   repetition condition      value
1           1         a -1.1366280
2           2         a -0.9885753
3           3         a -0.3114876
4           1         b -1.2965404
5           2         b -0.9456910
6           3         b -1.1366280
7           1         c -0.9885753
8           2         c -0.3114876
9           3         c -1.2965404
10          1         d -0.9456910
11          2         d -1.1366280
12          3         d -0.9885753
13          1         e -0.3114876
14          2         e -1.2965404
15          3         e -0.9456910
```

and a second dataframe that contains "reference" values for each of the five levels of the factor.

```
df2 <-
    data.frame(
        condition = letters[1:5],
        mean = rnorm(5)
    )
```

and looks like:

```
  condition  reference
1         a  0.1839216
2         b -0.2920561
3         c  0.1306390
4         d  0.1051630
5         e  0.5171277
```

I would like to substract to each observation in `df1` the corresponding reference value stored in `df2`. For instance, I would like to substract to each repetition value of level `a` (i.e., the first three lines of `df1`), the `reference` value for `a`, and then do it for each level (b, c, d, e).

How course, this is a really simplified reproducible example, the dataset I am working with is more complex, and so I would need a generic solution. Also, a solution without loops would be appreciated.

How could I do that ? Any dplyr solution ?

Thanks !

PS: I also welcome suggestions to improve the question formulation...

Comment: Good luck subtracting text or factor values.... Step 1 for improving the question would be to avoid using `data.frame(cbind(...)`  and just use `data.frame(...)`.

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but it's best to avoid using `cbind()` in your `data.frame` as those coerce the data.types of your columns. Everything should work fine if you leave out the `cbind` and pass those values directly to `data.frame.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edited the code.

Comment: @LadislasNalborczyk, appreciate the edits. The linked question from akrun should help you with your answer. Another suggestion: use `set.seed` to make your question reproducible if you're using anything with random number generation.